# Spring JPA Repository in one JAR cannot be used in another war

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jar, war

I have a very simple Spring JPA Repository which is packed into a JAR and stored in the local maven repository.
I can use the JPA Repository in my Unit-Tests and in a little Main-Test-Routine. It gets @Autowired without any problem.
Here is the definition of my JPA-Repository:

```
public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository<Seminar , Integer > {
List<Seminar> findAll();
```

}

And in the applicationContext.xml of the JAR:

```
    <jpa:repositories base-package="de.dmsb.my.core"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager">
</jpa:repositories>
```

There a also some other Services defined in this JAR too which can be used in the JAR and in the WAR, which includes the JAR as a dependency with maven.

But as soon as a try to @Autowire the the JPA-Repository:

```
@Autowired
TestRepo testRepo;
```

I get an runtime error that there is no suitable bean defined. Other beans work - but as soon as it comes to JPA-Repositories it doesn't work.

I mean of course you cannot @Autowire a interface - and in the WAR there is not JPA-Repository bean in the ApplicationContext when I debug it - all the other beans from the JAR are there.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you import the applicationContext.xml file of the jar in the web application's spring configuration? If you didn't, then the webapp doesn't know anything about this configuration, and won't magically configure spring-data.

Comment: No - I did not import the applicationContext.xml from the JAR into the WAR.
How can I import a applicationContext.xml and a Java-Configuration class?

Comment: Then it's just another library containing classes. The applicationContext.xml file it contains is not used by anybody.

Comment: Well the thing is: All the other services defined in the applicationContext.xml of the JAR are accessible from the WAR. Only the JPA-Repository is not injectable at runtime.

Comment: That's probably because your actual webapp spring configuration is configured to scan the packages where the services are defined, but is not configured to use spring-data-jpa.

Comment: I imported the applicationContext.xml from the JAR and now it works. I guess through the import the JPA-Proxies are created - which was not the case before. So this seems like the solution.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hey Frank, I am facing similar issue. Not able to utilise JpaRepositories from jar, even after importing the config.xml. Can you please go through the query which I have posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791448/spring-mvc-with-jpa-not-able-to-instantiate-jparepository-from-a-jar/40800469?noredirect=1#comment68824713_40800469